# Make a rewritten field from Views work in autocomplete

Tags: views, ajax

I have a view which lists all the terms from a vocabulary (400+ terms) as an HTML list. The taxonomy names are rewritten to be output as links and have two arguments: the TID of the current term (the view appears as a block only on taxonomy term pages) and the TID of the taxonomy term that's being displayed/clicked. I did this in order to implement a taxonomy comparison functionality.

My problem is that I need to have an autocomplete field for the terms in the block, since I can't show all the 400+ items at once. I tried the [Views Autocomplete Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) and [Finder](https://www.drupal.org/project/finder) modules, but neither of these wants to integrate with the rewritten field or I simply haven't found a way to set them up. Every time I use the rewritten Taxonomy: Name field, it just behaves like a regular field linking to its own content.

How can I implement this functionality?